# avconv / ffmpeg webcam capture while using minimum CPU processing

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, libav, avconv, webcam-capture

I have a question about avconv (or ffmpeg) usage.

My goal is to capture video from a webcam and saving it to a file.
Also, I don't want to use too much CPU processing. (I don't want avconv to scale or re-encode the stream)

So, I was thinking to use the compressed mjpeg video stream from the webcam and directly saving it to a file.

My webcam is a Microsoft LifeCam HD 3000 and its capabilities are:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0

Raw: yuyv422 : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV) : 640x480 1280x720 960x544 800x448 640x360 424x240 352x288 320x240 800x600 176x144 160x120 1280x800

Compressed: mjpeg : MJPEG : 640x480 1280x720 960x544 800x448 640x360 800x600 416x240 352x288 176x144 320x240 160x120
```

What would be the avconv command to save the Compressed stream directly without having avconv doing scaling or re-encoding.

For now, I am using this command:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -r 30 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 test.avi
```

I'm not sure that this command is CPU efficient since I don't tell anywhere to use the mjpeg Compressed capability of the webcam.

Is avconv taking care of the configuration of the webcam setting before starting to record the file ? Is it always working of raw stream and doing scaling and enconding on the raw stream ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: without using "-c copy" it'll do a re-encoding...if you want a "fast" re encoding I'd recommend x264 "fast" presets: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Answer (score 6):

Reading the [actual documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Options-17)™ is the closest thing to magic you'll get in real life:

> **video4linux2, v4l2**
>
> **input_format**
>
> Set the preferred pixel format (for raw video) or a codec name. This option allows one to select the input format, when several are available.
>
> **video_size**
>
> Set the video frame size. The argument must be a string in the form WIDTHxHEIGHT or a valid size abbreviation.

The command uses `-c:v copy` to just copy the received encoding without touching it therefore achieving the lowest resource use:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy <output>
```

Comment: I tried both ffmpeg and avconv and I have a warning message:  Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 166010, current: 16998; changing to 166011. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.     Does it mean my computer can't handle the stream properly ?

Comment: Are you using the [latest](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) `ffmpeg` or whatever came with your distro? Did you notice any issues with the output?

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg or avconv version provided with the distro. The video output has some lags/jump ... I think it is related to the warning "Non-monotonous DTS message". It seems it's happening more often with my Microsoft HD3000 webcam that other webcam. I will try with latest version... (I suppose that mean I have to built the tool from source?)

Comment: @user3585723 There are also static builds and packages available on https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html